# How to rethrow error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When there's an error I would like to do some cleanup and then let the error flow up so that it's handled globally.

In C# I would do a `try finally` but that is not possible with VBA, only `On Eror GoTo <mylabel>`.

How can I rethrow the error properly when caught in the label?

Is it only possible calling Err.Raise again with all properties, no `throw` like keyword exists?:

```
Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
```

Comment: You pretty much nailed it. I'd personally leave the `Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext` bit off though.

Comment: How is `Err.Raise` really different from `throw`? You can treat it like a keyword.

Comment: @JohnColeman Because I'm not sure whether this is the proper way to 'rethrow'. In C# for example you can just throw without creating a new exception instance.

Comment: @Comintern Why shouldn't I pass the `Err.HelpFile` and `Err.HelpContext`?

Answer (score 5):

That is the correct method, but no, you don't have to re-state all the err properties.  The values are retained:

```
err.raise Err.Number
```

is the same as

```
Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/raise-method

It can be more complex if you are throwing out of a class module. By default, the err object of a class module is caught and re-created, so depending on how it is declared, properties may be replaced.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without losing the call stack? That would allow for a "try-finally" pattern while preserving the ability to debug the call stack properly.

Comment: @rudolfbyker. No inbuilt method of retaining the call stack. you can do it yourself, or use MZtools to code it for you.

Answer (score -2):

I think that you should use ON ERROR GOTO...

And continue your error handling inside the "next_step"

For example:

```
Sub test()
    'IF OCCOUR ERROR INSIDE THIS BLOCK THE ERROR CONTINUE IN "next_step"
    On Error GoTo next_step

    If Err.Number = 10 Then
        Msgbox"Error!"
    End If

    next_step:
    'YOU CAN CONTINUE YOUR CODE HERE!!

End Sub
```