# proper error handling for resetting Hourglass

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling

I have a project with a number of instances of

```
    DoCmd.Hourglass -1
        <various code>
    DoCmd.Hourglass 0
    <other code>
```

Any time there is an error, the line turning off the hourglass gets skipped. The users get confused and wait for the app to be ready again.

Normally, I'd handle this in a try..finally

```
 try {
    DoCmd.Hourglass -1
        <various code>
 } finally {
    DoCmd.Hourglass 0
 }
```

but that isn't an option in VBA.
I thought it would be a simple matter to search and find the correct approach, but *every* sample I found takes the naïve approach above.

The trick is that I don't want to affect any of the existing program flow, which means that I need to rethrow the error.
And, of course, "throw" doesn't exist either.
But it also means that I do NOT need to resume where the error happened.

Here's my current best guess

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    DoCmd.Hourglass -1
        <various code>
    DoCmd.Hourglass 0
    <other code>
Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    DoCmd.Hourglass 0
    Err.Raise Err.Number
End Function
```

but I have 0 confidence that this is the best solution.

Comment: Need an Exit block and Resume Exit. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html

Comment: For a more enlightened approach to error handling try reading https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/05/09/pattern-tryparse/?like_comment=1119.  This article also addresses your missing try/catch issue and rethrowing of errors.

Comment: Seems to me that both of these approaches are solving a different problem and would alter the flow of the program by swallowing the error. We want to imitate a 'finally' clause which does not swallow the error.

Comment: @freeflow "addresses ... rethrowing of errors" Either I need more hand-holding or it doesn't talk about throwing or rethrowing, other than to say that you probably don't need it.

Comment: The error condition is contained within the try function.  If you have used the try function along the lines of 'If Not Try...     End if' the contained block of code is where you decide how you are going to handle the false returned from the Try function.  One of your options is to just raise a VBA error.  The point is that whether or not you raise an error is now under your control and not that of a global error handler in VBA.

Comment: @freeflow Perhaps I'm not following, but it sounds like you are saying to swallow all the error information and return false, then detect the false and throw a generic VBA error. But that will certainly change the behavior of higher level functions that are looking for specific errors to handle. This doesn't seem like an improvement on my suggested solution. The goal is to not change the existing behavior or flow, other than to turn off the hourglass, thus mimicking a try..finally clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64478691/1513027

```
err.raise Err.Number

This is the correct method, and no, you don't have to re-state all the err properties. The values are retained.
```